Apache Shiro and OTP (One Time Password)
I have a Maven project running with Tomcat 10.1.20 and JDK 21.
Apache Shiro 2.0 works well, but now I want to integrate an OTP (One Time Password) validation during the login phase (after the user has entered username and password)
I googled and found these (very old) articles:
Apache Shiro and Multi-factor Authentication
and
Two factor authentication using SHIRO
so should I use a webfilter or does Shiro have a built-in feature for this?
